# Error: trouble configuring builtin PatchTransformer with config

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kustomize

I ran into this problem. I have metadata.name. But I have no more ideas how to solve this problem. This kustomize used to work, but lately it just refuses to work. Can you please advise me

```
Client Version: v1.25.2
Kustomize Version: v4.5.7
```

This is what the error is displayed on the command line

```
Error: trouble configuring builtin PatchTransformer with config: `
patch: |-
  apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    name: core-keycloak
  spec:
    template:
      spec:
        containers:
          - name: core-keycloak
            resources:
              requests:
                cpu: '4'
                memory: '4Gi'
            startupProbe:
              initialDelaySeconds: 10
              timeoutSeconds: 30
              failureThreshold: 2
              exec:
                command:
                  - 'sh'
                  - '-cx'
                  - 'postStart.sh >> /proc/1/fd/1 2>&1'
            volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: /etc/x509/https
                name: tls-mount
            lifecycle:
              : delete
        volumes:
          - name: tls-mount
            secret:
              secretName: internal-cert
`: unable to parse SM or JSON patch from [apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: core-keycloak
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: core-keycloak
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: '4'
              memory: '4Gi'
          startupProbe:
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 30
            failureThreshold: 2
            exec:
              command:
                - 'sh'
                - '-cx'
                - 'postStart.sh >> /proc/1/fd/1 2>&1'
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /etc/x509/https
              name: tls-mount
          lifecycle:
            : delete
      volumes:
        - name: tls-mount
          secret:
            secretName: internal-cert]
```

I tried different options and without metadata, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
lifecycle:
  : delete
```

The variable was not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and my problem was a tab before the `image` field in a yaml file so simple as this one:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
    image: nginx:latest
```

Try to validate your yaml file in some tool (like [this one](https://validkube.com/)). I found this problem on my file after a lot of time trying to understand what was wrong with it.